# downloading baxter sdk on ros humble

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, baxter

I need some help, currently following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J47SKs0QRyU) to download the baxter sdk, everything is fine until i reach the catkin_make part , realised catkin_make doesnt work with ros2, and cant find any documentation on the ros2 humble wiki on how to download the baxter sdk, any info would be great.

If you have a link to a tutorial, even better.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the Baxter SDK is compatible with any distribution of ROS 2.

The tutorial you are following is for ROS 1. And it's most likely that the SDK hasn't been ported to ROS 2 if you can't find any documentation about it for ROS 2.

PS as feedback on your question please link to things like "the Baxter SDK" so that everyone is on the same page. I can't provide better info without a specific reference or at least package name.

Answer (score 0):

As Tully said I don't think there is an official SDK for ROS 2.
If you follow the oficial support guide there it says it only works with ROS 1 distributions (Indigo, Melodic, Kinetic and Noetic): https://support.rethinkrobotics.com/support/solutions/articles/80000980134-workstation-setup
From my experience using baxter the best version to run baxter SDK is ROS Indigo. If you still need to control Baxter with ROS 2 you can try something I do with pepper, use a docker in ROS noetic to enable robot topics and after that use another docker or native ROS foxy installation with ROS bridge to publish messages to ROS 1 topics.